# Bootstrap 3 horizontal tabs on desktop, vertical tabs on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code

```
<div class="row">
<h4>Categories</h4>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#0" class="thumbnail">All Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1" class="thumbnail">Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1" class="thumbnail">Vehicles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1" class="thumbnail">Firearms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

which produces this on desktop browsers

[image]

but on mobile it looks like this

[image]

If I add class `nav-stacked` to the ul **I get what I am looking** for on mobile like so:

[image]

but it is also stacked on desktop. I would like the tabs to be horizontal as in the first image on desktop browsers, but vertical tabs on mobile. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Well you could use media queries which will allow you to change the class depending on screen size

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3, which contains the media queries needed for each screen size

Comment: It contains media queries for things it wants to change at what breakpoint, what you want to do is not ordinary for Bootstrap so you can add your own override

Comment: Ok, I guess that could be a solution but I was hoping that there is a class or classes that I could apply to the elements to make them act as desired

Comment: you can use screen size as Darren said. If your screen is < or > than size set what you want. Look here it may help to you http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [justified navs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified). They will be stretched to the width of their parent container on large viewports and stacked vertically on small screens.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  ...
</ul>
```

Or, you can add a media query which mimics the behavior of `.nav-justified`:

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .nav-tabs > li {
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Under `@media (max-width: 767px) ` I added `.nav-tabs > li { display:block; width: 100%;}` and it works as I need.

Comment: @Angelo: I think you need to disable the float; setting the width shouldn't be necessary. I've updated my answer

Comment: Using your updated answer looks better than using `width:100%`. Works as needed

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
     $('.nav-tabs').addClass('nav-stacked');
    }
    else {$('.nav-tabs').removeClass('nav-stacked');}
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
<h4>Categories</h4>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#0" class="thumbnail">All Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1" class="thumbnail">Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1" class="thumbnail">Vehicles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1" class="thumbnail">Firearms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```